# Replace a variable inside a typescript file from windows batch script

Tags: angular, windows, batch-file, webpack, build

I want to modify a typescript file which holds the environment information inside an angular 6 project. The variable value must be changed only at the time of a build, which is initiated a through a batch file.

The environment file look as follows: (where the build is the variable to be changed/replaced)

```
export const environment = {
  host: 'http://localhost:8080',
  build: "1.0.0.0"
};
```

I am finding difficult to do the same via batch file. The environment file is different for different environments (local/qa/dev/prod), and the build is initiated by a build engineer.
 The current build process calls the webpack command, and zips the output.

Is there a way to replace the 'build' value dynamically from each build?

**Edit**:
  Figured out a way inspired from https://www.bilyachat.com/blog/angular-2-build-version. Will update as an answer soon.

Comment: May be you need to wait. This is still open from angular side https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4318

Comment: In angular.json you has a fileReplacements "tag"

Comment: @Eliseo Unfortunately I am not using angular.cli, but webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it on my own.
My solution is:

1. Added a variable inside the config files, meant for each environment
2. Added '[replace-in-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file)' node library for replacing particular content (variable- 
   '%VERSION%'), which was inside the particular config file, with the value passed 
   while calling the `ng-build-qa: node ./replace.build.js` command in `package.json`
3. The content of '`replace.build.js` file is:

```
var replace = require('replace-in-file');
var buildVersion = process.argv[2];
const options = {
    files: 'environments/environment.qa.ts',
    from: "%VERSION%",
    to: ""+ buildVersion + "",
    allowEmptyPaths: false,
};

try {
    let changedFiles = replace.sync(options);
    if (changedFiles == 0) {
        throw "Please make sure that file '" + options.files + "' has \"version: ''\"";
    }
    console.log('Build version set: ' + buildVersion);
}
catch (error) {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error);
    throw error
}
```